# How to declare an array with macros in Lauterbach CMM script

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I would like to create an array with Macros in Lauterbach CMM script.

I tried the following:

```
LOCAL &ARRAY_VAR[10]
```

This syntax doesn't work.

I know how to create array with Var.NEWLOCAL:

```
Var.NEWLOCAL int[3] \ARRAY_VAR
```

Is there any way to create macros with array?

Comment: Hi Holger
Do you have any idea how I can I declare an array with Private macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: PRACTICE does not support macro arrays.

---

**Longer answer**: PRACTICE can do a recursive macro expansion, which allows you to do something similar than real arrays. 
(See "PRACTICE Macros" in [practice_user.pdf](https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/practice_user.pdf))

E.g.:

```
LOCAL &myarr0 &myarr1 &myarr2 &myarr3   
LOCAL &data &i

&data="zero|one|two|three"

// Assign values to &myarra0 to &myarra3 in a loop
&i=0.
WHILE &i<4.
(
    PRIVATE &cmd
    &cmd="&"+"myarr"+FORMAT.Decimal(1,&i)+"=STRing.SPLIT(""&"+"data"",""|"",&i)"
    &&cmd   // << evaluate with recursive macro expansion
    &i=&i+1.
)

// Print values saved in &myarra0 to &myarra3 in a loop
&i=0.
WHILE &i<4.
(
    PRIVATE &val
    &val="&"+"myarr"+FORMAT.Decimal(1,&i)
    &&val="&val"   // << assign with recursive macro expansion
    ECHO "&val"
    &i=&i+1.
)
```

If you don't care of having too many GLOBAL macros you can also create the pseudo-array in a loop like this:

```
LOCAL &i
&i=0
WHILE &i<4.
(
    PRIVATE &cmd
    &cmd="GLOBAL "+"&"+"myarr"+FORMAT.Decimal(1,&i)
    &cmd
    &i=&i+1
)
```

I wouldn't do that because I don't like GLOBAL macros.

---

**Workaround**: Create an array with Var.NEWLOCAL

E.g.:

```
Var.NEWLOCAL char[4][32] \myarr
LOCAL &i &data

&data="zero|one|two|three"

// Assign values to \myarr in a loop
&i=0.
WHILE &i<4
(
    PRIVATE &val
    &val=STRing.SPLIT("&data","|",&i)
    Var.Assign \myarr[&i]="&val"
    &i=&i+1.
)

// Print values saved in \myarr in a loop
&i=0.
WHILE &i<4
(
    ECHO Var.STRing(\myarr[&i])
    &i=&i+1.
)
```